# Fixing date labels when plotting bar chart of resampled Pandas time series data in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Using the command `monthly[monthly.columns[:3]].resample('Q').sum()` in pandas, I create a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
DateIndex   C1  C2  C3    
2012-09-30  94  139 181
2012-12-31  111 236 162
2013-03-31  113 321 259
2013-06-30  96  238 219
```

I can then plot those numbers using the command `monthly[monthly.columns[:3]].resample('Q').sum().plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)` to produce a figure that looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of resampled quarterly bar plot]

**What I can't do is fix the x-axis date labels so they're not so ugly.**

Using Matplotlib's `.bar` function, described [here](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), might be a better option. But I can't work out how to get the DateIndex into the right format so `.plot` will accept `x` and `y` variables. Matplotlib also has a [useful page about date labels](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/api/date.html), but those commands don't seem to work the with Pandas `.plot` function. Can you help? I've hunted around on here but so far not discovered a solution that works for me. Thanks!

Comment: you can convert the datetime to date, by using dt.date

Answer (score 1):

```
y = monthly[monthly.columns[:3]].resample('Q').sum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
y.plot(ax=ax,kind='bar',stacked=True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(y.index.to_period('Q'))
```